# Allocate 2D char array malloc or calloc

Tags: c, string, malloc, calloc, dynamic-allocation

I've recently decided to brush up my C knowledge (what little of it I have left). I quite quickly realized that the first *skill* to go cloudy was memory management. Damned.

I decided that the best thing to do, was to write some pointless pointer exercises. The first one was to allocate an array of 4 char arrays, each of which were of variable length.

A simplified version of that code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char **aStr = malloc(4*sizeof(aStr));
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<sizeof(aStr))
    {
        j = 4 + 2*i;//in my code, length is determined by arguments
        aStr[i] = malloc(j*sizeof(aStr[i]));
        j--;
        strncpy(aStr[i],"RaisinRubarbCarrot"+i,j);
        aStr[i][j] = 0;//just a habbit
        j++;
        printf("ptr@:%p\n\tkey:%d\n\tval:%s\n\tlength:%d (%d)\n\n",*aStr[i],i,aStr[i],j,strlen(aStr[i]));
        i++;
    }
    free(aStr);
    return 0;
}
```

I felt this to be clunky, and counter-intuitive. Today I remembered my old nemisis: `calloc`. I then wrote

```
char **aStr = (char **)calloc(4, sizeof(char *));
```

and in the loop:

```
aStr[i] = (char *) calloc(j,sizeof(char *));
```

I have found code examples that write the last line like so:

```
aStr[i] = (char *) calloc(j,sizeof(char));//without the asterisk
```

Question 1: what's the difference, if any?

Question 2: Isn't there another way of allocating an array of strings? the way I see the code now, it feels/looks like I am first allocating 4 pointers to a single char pointer, and then allocating the actual size required for each pointer. That just feels wrong.

Then again I might be wrong about all of this all together, in which case: feel free to bang my head against the wall and point me in the direction of a decent manual I should read before wasting all of your time...

Comment: `aStr[i] = (char *) calloc(j,sizeof(char));` not `sizeof(char *)`

Comment: @Gir, I thought so, strangely, both compile just fine, no warnings issued

Comment: so? i doesnt mean its correct. it doesn't complain because a) you cast both results to the right type b) it doesnt know what you want to do. i am not even sure you need to cast

Comment: @Gir: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, and you shouldn't cast. So it should be `aStr[i] = calloc(j, 1);` only.

Comment: sizeof(char) might be morereadable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *` and `char` are two different types, and have different data sizes. A `char` is always a single byte, so `sizeof(char)` is always *1*. A *pointer to char* on the other hand, will be 4 bytes on a 32bit system. So if you use `sizeof(char*)` to allocate space for a string, you'll be allocating much more than you need.

Using the loop to allocate the individual strings is fine. Assuming a maximum length for your strings, you *could* just allocate one big block, but that would be clumsy.

Comment: So which of the two methods is to be preferred? `calloc` or `malloc`, because in both cases the code does the same thing. I'm currently using `calloc` because it fits the goal better IMO

Comment: `calloc` initializes the data elements to zero for you, and so can prevent certain errors. Otherwise they're equivalent: just use which one you think reads better. But if you use `malloc` be aware that the memory isn't initialized to anything and will be filled with junk data.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use sizeof(char) instead of sizeof(char*) because you are trying to allocate memory for an array of chars not an array of poiners to chars. So this is the right version:

   ```
   aStr[i] = (char*) calloc(j, sizeof(char)); 
   //first argument number of memory
   //locations to be allocated
   //second argument, size of each location
   ```

   The difference/advantage of calloc over malloc is that it also initialized the memory locations to 0.
2. You first allocate an array of 4 pointers to chars. And then, you allocate memory for each of the strings (each of the 4 pointers previously allocated will point to one of these arrays)

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` though.